# Sidebar grid with tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, css-grid, tailwind-css

I'm new with Tailwind, I read the docs and do not understand how gird works!

I need to reach like this shap:

[image]

My wrong try:

```
<div class="grid grid-rows-3 grid-flow-col gap-4">
    <div class="col-span-2 ...">col 1</div>
    <div class="col-span-2 ...">col 2</div>
    <div class="col-span-2 ...">col 3</div>
    <div class="row-span-3 ...">col 4</div>
    <div class="row-span-3 ...">sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `col-span`s from all cells and add `col-end-3` to your 2nd and 4th cells.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="grid grid-rows-3 grid-flow-col gap-4">
  <div class="border">col 1</div>
  <div class="border col-end-3">col 2</div>
  <div class="border">col 3</div>
  <div class="border col-end-3">col 4</div>
  <div class="border row-span-3">sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if cols are dynamic from the loop I mean? how can I deal with "col-end-3"

Comment: What is dynamic exactly? The number of columns in the grid, or the number of items you want to display in the grid? Could you please add more details to your original question about that?

Comment: I mean by dynamic the columns gonna be from the "foreach" and you just give it "col-end-3" but with foreach I can not specify which one will be the second!

Comment: You can, items with an odd index in your loop (1, 3, 5, etc.) will correspond to the cells that require `col-end-3` added to them.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it but it does not should be like this way, it should there is a way to do it without $index! or that is let us to back to bootstrap 

Comment: I just solve the problem with the nested grid!  but I got another problem with the height of each grid :( do you know how to remove the height that been made by the grid?